# JavaScript submit does not work at times in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a custom dialog box which takes user input and submit the form based on user input. This JavaScript works fine on IE and Firefox. It also works on Chrome at times but at times there is no response.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onblur = function() { 
        window.focus(); 
        }

        var realtimePoLink = "./processAbc.do";
        var realtimePoMethod = "startAbc";
        var nightlyPoLink = "./processXyz.do";
        var nightlyPoMethod= "startXyz";



        function startPO(){
            var historyPoRadio = document.getElementById("nightlyPoRadio");
            if(historyPoRadio !=null && historyPoRadio.checked == true){
                document.getElementById("method").value = nightlyPoMethod;
                document.getElementById("poStartForm").action = nightlyPoLink;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("method").value = realtimePoMethod;
                document.getElementById("poStartForm").action = realtimePoLink;
            }
            document.forms["poStartForm"].submit();
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="poStartForm" id ="poStartForm" method="POST" action="" target="ASSIAMainWindow">
            <input type="hidden" name="tn" value="0000010019">
            <input type="hidden" name="portId" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="method" id="method" value="startPo">
            <input type="hidden" name="confirmation" value="YES">
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="poSourceValue" value="1" checked="checked">
                    <td>ABC
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="poSourceValue" value="2">
                    <td>MNO
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="poSourceValue" value="3" id="nightlyPoRadio">
                    <td>XYZ
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="javascript:startPO();"/>
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:window.close();"/>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Irrespective of whether the form is submitted or not the dialog box is always closed.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Is this form being used in a popup window? Where is it posting to? Is it part of a framed page?

Comment: @DaveNewton Nothing in the console. Everything seems fine

Comment: @Tom Yes this form is used in a pop up window (a custom dialog box).